# Is there a standard way to read man pages?

Tags: c, manpage

I want to access man pages from my application.

I know I can use the `system` function and execute shell commands like this:

```c
system("man cat");
```

but I wanted to know if there is something more secure.

Comment: You can look at the raw source for them, which on Unix systems you can find in `/usr/share/man` or someplace similar.  These are gzipped `troff` files.  You can unzip them with `gzip`.  To format them, you need to run them through `troff` or some related utility.  I don't think it's likely to be very helpful though.

Comment: @TomKarzes Thank you very much! Can you say how can I use `troff` to format that files? Do I just need to do something like `troff /usr/share/man/bash.1`?

Comment: There are some options that need to be passed to `troff` that define macros and such needed by the man pages.  I think it can produce postscript output.  But for your purposes, it's probably easiest to invoke `man --ascii page` where `page` is the man page name (e.g. `cat`, or `printf(3)`).  You can them capture the outpout, which will be plain (but formatted) ascii text.  That will be every bit as secure as invoking `troff`, and you'll have the text captured so you can then display it any way you like.